# Asp.net Core User Selectable CSS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'd like my users to be able to change the css file being loaded, in order to apply themes. I'd load the regular css and then load another "theme" css afterwards like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/dark_theme.css" />
```

I have a basic understanding of how this would be achieved, but i'm interested to hear of the most efficient way. I'd likely have a string in the user's model called "ThemeName" and have that updated per a select form in their control panel. I'd make the select options the same as the css file name and just insert the model's value into the view like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
@if (User.ThemeName != null) {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/{User.ThemeName}.css" />
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you have a reasonable approach and idea in your head on how this is going to work. What exactly do you need help with? "Most efficient" is subjective and can't really be answered beyond throwing some opinions around.

Comment: I'm quite new to asp.net core and wasn't sure if there was an "official" way of using themes. I did read some things (http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-core-themes-and-multi-tenancy) but using multiple views seems silly?
I was just checking that this would be a good way to do this, sorry if my "question" is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did this exactly as i explained in the question.

Partial View:

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    if (UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ThemeName != null && UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ThemeName != "Default")
    {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/@(UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.ThemeName).css" />
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
// POST: /Manage/ChangeTheme
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeTheme(ChangeThemeViewModel model)
{
    var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();

    if (user == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    user.ThemeName = model.Theme;

    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

I'll expand on this by storing ThemeName as a cookie / session, to avoid a query on every single page request, and to allow anonymous users to take advantage of a dark theme.